# How to select weight (amount of fire retardant) in Fire-Extinguisher

Tags: fire

Reference: https://www.qrfs.com/blog/66-ultimate-guide-to-fire-extinguisher-types-servicing-and-uses/

I have an multi-use office and residential building.  I am interested in not only meeting code, but genuinely protecting the my family's property from fire.  What is the line of thought to decide the right weight?  Choice include 2.5,5,10,& 20 lbs.  Customers might not be able to lift the heaviest unit.

Comment: Sprinklers. For extinguishers, more is better up to the point that "can't lift it" becomes a problem, accepting the fact that ANY use means recharging the whole extinguisher (or replacing if the extinguisher is not a serviceable/rechargeable unit.)

Comment: 2A-10BC is minimum (I believe) for commercial spaces, e.g. your office area(s). You should check with your local Fire Dept. and have them come and look at your office space. They will tell you minimum number that you legally need. Like @Ecnerwal mentions, you need to consider who might need to use them before you upsize. You could always install several, instead of one giant one.